# Plot label doesn't show up in GraphicsGrid

Tags: plotting, labeling, grid-layouts

```
M1ParameterBigList = RandomVariate[
       InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[10, IdentityMatrix[3]], {5, 100}];


rangeTrace = 5;
plotM1Data = ParallelTable[
       ListPlot[M1ParameterBigList[[t, ;; , i, j]], 
        PlotLabel -> 
         "M" <> ToString[{i, j}] <> "  Period - " <> ToString[t], 
        Joined -> True], {t, 1, rangeTrace}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];

plotM1Traces = 
     GraphicsGrid[{Table[
        GraphicsGrid[plotM1Data[[i]]], {i, 1, rangeTrace}]}, 
      ImageSize -> {3500, 900}, ImagePadding -> All]
```

And the image I get it the following:
[image]

There are two 2 things I would like to change in the picture:

1. The final picture is very small, nothing like what I see in the notebook. Can we make it bigger in the exported file?
2. The labels of the upper graphs don't show up completely... I've tried using a different image size, but that will make the problem in point 1 even worse, I think...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: since each 3X3 block is symmetric, you can eliminate the upper diagonal using  `{j, 1, i}` as the last iterator in `plotM1Data` (this seems to get rid of the second issue on version 12 / WolframCloud)

Comment: @kglr thanks for your comment. I've tried what you suggest, while also using version 12, and it doesn't seem to work. The labels still don't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out how to solve this:

```
plotM1Traces = 
 GraphicsGrid[{Table[
    GraphicsGrid[plotM1Data[[i]], ImageMargins -> 0, 
     ImagePadding -> Full, ImageSize -> {1000, 600}], {i, 1, 
     rangeTrace}]}, ImageSize -> {5000, 600}]
```

Each individual graphic grid must occupy an equal share of space in the whole graphic grid.